# Magnolia (6.2) chooser ChooseAction availability by node type

Tags: dialog, action, magnolia

I'm trying to limit the choose action to a certain node type. The definitions app is not showing any errors, but the choose button is still active all the time. This is the chooser definition I'm using:

```
!inherit:ui-framework-jcr:chooser
  actions:
    choose:
      availability:
        nodeTypes:
          - shopTaxCategory
```

I did notice that one of the parent classes of the `info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.action.ChooseActionDefinition` sets the availability in its constructor. Although the `setAvailability()` method is still available, when initialising the dialog, the constructors are called multiple times(?!) and even though the availability is set to what is configured, in the end it is overwritten again by what is in that parent class. Therefore I created my own `ConfigurableChooseActionDefinition` which does not set the availability by itself. Now, the availability is set according to the configuration as it is displayed in the Definitions app:
[image]
Unfortunately the "Choose" button is still active all the time no matter what node is selected in the chooser:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, my idea about the `ConfigurableChooseActionDefinition` was in fact correct.

```
public class ConfigurableChooseActionDefinition extends ConfiguredActionDefinition {
    public static final String CHOOSE_ACTION_NAME = "choose";

    public ConfigurableChooseActionDefinition() {
        this.setImplementationClass(ChooseAction.class);
        this.setName(CHOOSE_ACTION_NAME);
    }

    ConfigurableChooseActionDefinition(String name) {
        this();
        this.setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getShortcut() {
        return ENTER;
    }
}
```

However I must have messed up something with the `$linkField` configuration. The chooser with the `ConfigurableChooseActionDefinition` was not even used. When configured correctly, the "Choose"-button is in fact disabled when the user selects a node which is not listed in the `availability/nodeTypes` of the chooser dialog:
[image]